# jQuery to replace images with content

Tags: jquery, image, replace

**GOAL:**

To fadeIn() the 'company-content' when the logo image is CLICKED ON *AND* fading out all of the other content in the 'tiles-wrapper' DIV.  The COMPANY CONTENT will be the same width as the full 'tiles-wrapper' display DIV.

THEN...

When the 'company-content' is displayed, the BACK link returns the page to it's original state.

Do I need to use 2 separate UL's with unique class names for 'company-logos' and 'company-content' (= trash the 'li.content-wrapper' idea) vs. the posted code?

**I have actually done this before.  I'm losing my mind.  I can't remember how I did this.  Any suggestions are appreciated.*

```
<div class="tiles-wrapper">
    <ul class="tiles-list">
        <li class="company-wrapper">
            <div class="company-logo"><a class="company-logo-btn" href="#"><img src="company1.png" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
            <div class="company-content">
                <h1>Company 1</h1>
                <div class="goback"><a class="goback-btn" href="#">&larr; BACK TO ALL</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="company-wrapper">
            <div class="company-logo"><a class="company-logo-btn" href="#"><img src="company2.png" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
            <div class="company-content">
                <h1>Company 2</h1>
                <div class="goback-btn"><a class="goback-btn" href="#">&larr; BACK TO ALL</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="company-wrapper">
            <div class="company-logo"><a class="company-logo-btn" href="#"><img src="company3.png" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
            <div class="company-content">
                <h1>Company 3</h1>
                <div class="goback-btn"><a class="goback-btn" href="#">&larr; BACK TO ALL</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

... and looped in PHP to add more rows ...

[image: Initial display]
[image: Results display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Make the content width and height same of the tiles-wrapper but make it hidden,and use javascript to make effect.

JsCode:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".company-logo-btn").on("click", function () {
        var bRunOnce = true;
        var $wrapper = $(this).parents(".company-wrapper:first");
        $wrapper.siblings().fadeTo("slow", 0, function () {
            if (bRunOnce) {
                bRunOnce = false;
                $wrapper.find(".company-content").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".goback-btn", function () {
        $(".company-content:visible").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).parents(".company-wrapper:first").siblings().css("visibility","").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the [Demo on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trQTg/)

**Updated Again:**

I made a fade effect Demo,but I forget to update it in fiddle yesterday,Check [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trQTg/3/)

Comment: the site won't let me update the TYPO ".tiles-lis" to ".tiles-list"  ...  regardless ... I can't get this to work.  Can you please post the CSS that would accompany this?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstand your mean.I update the answer and write a simple demo on jsfiddle.But I don't know what the exactly animation look like especially the transform from 'click the logo image' to 'fade out the content'.So if I didn't something wrong,please tell me or look at the jsfiddle code and modify it by yourself(I suggest this way).

Comment: Your jsfiddle code is perfect!  I tried to make an update to your code above but this site wouldn't let me edit your code the way that I wanted.  (*So please edit the code in this post for others.)  **CRITICAL FOR FUTURE CODERS:  The JQ, the HTML and the CSS are all critical to have this function correctly.

Comment: I had a updated version in fiddle.If you changed something and you think you version is better to you post,just put it in you topic.